# Check sums clicks - can they be measured

Tags: civimail, webform-civicrm

Can I know how many people clicked on their checksum link to a webform?

I understand it can't work the same as other links as in a 10000 Strong mailing there would be 10000 links. I'm trying to see how many people who click on the webform complete it.

Thanks

Comment: Does the clickthrough get recorded at all? I just sent a test civimail with a checksum link to several of my email accounts. I clicked on two of them, but the clickthrough report shows 0 still

Comment: No it doesn't get recorded at all I don't think. I was just curious if anyone else had found away of measuring it - sounds like probably not.....

Comment: @carolineB - Is this the same question as this? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22287/how-can-i-track-donations-made-as-a-result-of-a-particular-email

Comment: I'm not sure it is actually. In this scenario you don't even know if someone clicked on the survey page at all unless you use google analytics

Answer (score 1):

Since you specifically want to know about checksum links to webforms, you could patch `webform_civicrm` to record something after it calls `CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact_Utils::validChecksum()` to validate the checksum.