# How can I track donations made as a result of a particular email?

Tags: civimail, contribution-page

I know that I can see who clicked through on the "donate" link on an email - but I don't see a way to check if the donation was made as part of that interaction.

Is there a way to determine this?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this (whilst not 100% foolproof) would be to create a special donation page for the link in the email (i.e. separate from the donation page that presumably appears as link and 'proper' page on your website).

Go to *Contributions >> New Contribution Page* or *Administer >> CiviContribute >> Manage Contribution Pages*.

Then once your new contribution page is complete, simply copy the URL you get from **Links >> Live Page** into where you have the donate link in your emails. It will look something like https://your-site.com/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2

As long as you don't link to that URL from anywhere else (like a button on your website), it should only ever be used by someone clicking on an email. You can then use a Contribution Report for that particular donation page.

It looks like you may also be able to do it with custom fields and passing URL parameters, but that's more complicated. See this entry in the wiki, from 2014: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Update+custom+fields+in+contributions+and+events+by+passing+variables+in+a+URL

Comment: Thanks for the answers Hugh!  I had considered both these options but hoped there was something simpler I was missing.  I may write an extension to implement the "pass a custom field via URL" technique, but it will handle automatically adding a mailing ID so as to reduce the learning curve for the end user.  Maybe by extending the "Fancy Tokens" extension.

Comment: Agreed that Hugh's suggestion is likely the intended solution. Jon: I like your ideas around adding extra information to the contribution via a url - if not in a custom field, perhaps by appending something to the contribution source field?  The 'civicampaign' feature is also designed for measuring the success of a campaign, though it's probably too large a sieve for answering the more specific question you're asking.

Comment: @AlanDixon I'd use the Campaign ID, but many larger organizations use email appeals as part of a larger campaign.  I'd like mailing-specific details.  This also should allow us to correlate folks who clicked through to the donation page from a link but didn't convert.

Comment: Random thought: assuming click-through are enabled, we could correlate with the contribution date/time? ex: for each click, if the contact has a contribution in the same day, count the revenue towards that mailing. Caveat: assumes working deduping.